# What to do in code for android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I am making an app for android which is completely based on fragments.
It has a menu and on clicking any item a fragment according to option opens.
I am confused how to put the code for the fragment in the class for fragment.I was reading a post here,in which a solution was provided to code the fragment like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // do your variables initialisations here except Views!!!



 }
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        libraryHeading=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.Library);   

        libraryHeading.setText("Hey I am Library");

        // initialise your views

 }
```

Now in onViewCreated() I will initialize views,in onCreate() I will initialize my variables but I am not getting what will I do in onCreateView()?
Please help me.I am new to android development.If I am doing something wrong please tell me.

Comment: Rather than copy code from S.O., you would be better served in following a tutorial to see more fully what is required for your question. You have instantiated a `Fragment` which is a start. 
- [Here is a good guide from the Android devs to learn about how fragments work](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
- [This one is pretty closely aligned with your stated goal](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what guide you're following.

In my applications, I do all of the view initialization in the `onCreateView()` method. So something like this:

```
TextView sampleTextView;
ImageView sampleImageView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml_layout, container, false);

    sampleTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
    sampleImageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sampleImageView);

    sampleTextView.setText("You can do all initialization here...");

    sampleImageView.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    return rootView;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // do your variables initializations here except Views
}
```

You can forget the whole `onViewCreated()` thing, at least for now. Just use the `onCreateView()` method the way I did above.

Comment: And why is onCreate() here.Can I remove this too??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901727/android-add-code-to-a-fragment/27679176#27679176

Comment: please check the link.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. You can do all of your variable initializations in `onCreateView()` if you want. I would do them in `onCreate()` because that's the common way to do it - and consistency is important.

Comment: @JustinJames I've seen the link. I haven't seen people use `onViewCreated()` very much before. You can initialize the variables in either one.

Comment: If you check the Android documentation, you will see that `onCreate()` is called while the activity is being created. It would be common practice to do non-view related initialization there.

Comment: Ok as you said I initialize the views in onCreateView() but I am sorry my app crashed.

Comment: @JustinJames go ahead and post a new question if that's an issue. It probably crashed because you used the wrong xml names or something.

Comment: @JustinJames yup. make sure to use rootView - it is the view that you create in the line at the top of that method. Also, if this is the correct answer, please mark it as the accepted response so it is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you very much.I understood it.It was happening due to this line:

```
libraryHeading=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.Library);
```

I should have to use rootView instead of getView() method

Answer (score 0):

As per docs

```
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)


Called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.
```

If you are accessing the view hierarchy of the parent activity then you must be done it in  the onActivityCreated, not before it.